# what is XNA development?

Tags: xna

can anyone provide me more information about XNA Development? for what usages it is good for?

Comment: Check http://creators.xna.com/en-US/

Comment: Google would have provide a lot of information in the first place... Even a search on this site would have provided a lot of information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is used to program games for the Xbox, PC and soon to be windows phone 7

Check out the [XNA site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791.aspx) for more info

Answer (score 2):

[XNA](http://creators.xna.com/) is a Microsoft programing environment for writing games that will run on both PCs and XBoxes.

Answer (score 2):

XNA is a .net framework api build on top of directx, and is aimed primarily at game development. It is designed to provide a easier to use managed framework for working with DirectX. One of the advantages to writing games build with xna is that you can deploy your game to PC's, XBox360, Window Phone 7, and even zune.

And the best part is that it is free! The xna framework and GSE (Game Studio Express) are both provided completely free of charge.

Although the xna framework leans more on game development it is also a viable tool/framework for presenting 2D/3D graphics for any .net application.

Check out the XNA site for more info, code examples etc

XNA has been steadily gaining penetration in both the indie and commercial games market. And a yearly game competition has been running called [Dream Build Play](http://www.dreambuildplay.com).

Answer (score 1):

[XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA) is set of tools, based on .NET framework, used for game development for various platforms (PC, Xbox, Zune). What could interest you (among other things) is XNA Framework and XNA Studio. You can check those out on [XNA homepage](http://creators.xna.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You should note that the future of XNA is currently doubtful:

> Presently the XNA Game Studio is not in active development and
>   DirectX is no longer evolving as a technology. Given the status within
>   each technology, further value and engagement cannot be offered to the
>   MVP community. As a result, effective April 1, 2014 XNA/DirectX will
>   be fully retired from the MVP Award Program.